# How to add an NSArray of filenames to a NSTableView? - cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nstableview

I need help figuring out how to display the contents of an NSArray into a NSTableView. My NSArray is filled with (or at least I think it is) filenames from a directory. I use NSFileManager to get the names of files in a directory and then I load that info into a NSArray. But I can't figure out how to load the NSArray into the NSTableView.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

NSArray *list;
IBOutlet NSTextField *text;

NSFileManager *manager;
NSString *path;
NSString *pathFinal;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (IBAction)listArray:(id)sender;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [list count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
        row:(int)row
{
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (IBAction)listArray:(id)sender {
    path = @"~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin/";
    pathFinal = [path stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    list = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:pathFinal];

    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: [Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/cocoabindings.html) using [`NSArrayController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or by implementing the [`NSTableDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol in an object and assigning that object as the table view's `datasource`.

It looks like you have already half-implemented the `NSTableViewDataSource` method. You need to add the protocol declaration to your interface to indicate that your `AppDelegate` object implements the protocol:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
```

You have already implemented the required datasource methods, so in theory everything should be working, but you possibly have not set your `AppDelegate` object as the table view's `datasource`. You can do this in code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [tableView setDatasource:self];
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign the datasource in Interface Builder by setting the table view's `datasource` outlet to your `AppDelegate` instance.

However, the main problem you have is that you are assigning an autoreleased object to your `list` ivar, and it is being released before the table view reloads.

Your `listArray` method is problematic. There is no reason for `path` and `pathFinal` to be instance variables. They are only used once, so should be locally scoped. In fact, since `path` is a constant, it should be declared separately:

```
//this should go in the top of your .m file, after the #import directives
static NSString* minecraftPath = @"~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin/";

- (IBAction)listArray:(id)sender 
{
    NSString* path = [minecraftPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

    //you want to hang onto the array that is returned here, so you must retain it
    //however, if you don't release the existing value, it will be leaked
    [list release];
    list = nil;
    list = [[manager directoryContentsAtPath:pathFinal] retain];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //because you retained it, you must release it
    [list release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

A much better way to do this would be to declare `list` as a property and synthesize its accessors:

**.h:**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource> {
 ...
}
...
@property (retain) NSArray* list;
...
```

**.m:**

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize list;
...
```

You can then use the property and it handles the retain/release for you:

```
- (IBAction)listArray:(id)sender 
{
    NSString* path = [minecraftPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

    //you've set the property to use retain, so the synthesized accessor does that for you
    self.list = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:pathFinal];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //you still need to release when done
    self.list = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. It's just not doing anything and I'm getting no errors in the log. When I put in the NSTableDataSource protocol, it said it wasn't found and told me to change it to NSTableViewDataSource, I don't know if that's the problem. And I have the table set as the datasource in IB and the delegate but stil nothing's happening. It also says that directoryContentsAtPath is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake with the protocol name, it is `NSTableViewDataSource`. You don't set the table view as the data source, you set the `AppController` object as the table view's data source. Connect the table view's `datasource` outlet to the `AppController` instance. `directoryContentsAtPath` ***is*** deprecated. If you look at the docs, it tells you to use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` instead, so do so.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I mis-worded that. I did have the table view's `datasource` connected to the `AppController`. But it's still not showing anything in the table and it says that no such instance method of `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`

Comment: Use [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW6). You need to read the documentation and use the method correctly.

Comment: I'm doing exactly what they say but now it says there's no method of `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` and it keeps crashing. I want to the docs first before coming here

Comment: HAHAHA yes! It works. Idk what I did beside change it back to just `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:` but it works now. Thank you

Comment: Ok but now how do I get the string value of the selected row? I've tried like `string = [[tableView selectedRow] stringValue]` and other stuff but it's not working.

Comment: You don't, you need to query the underlying data, in this case your `list` property. `NSString* string = [self.list objectAtIndex:[tableView selectedRow]];`. You need to read the docs and take note of what the method you are calling returns. `selectedRow` returns the index of the row, which is not an object.